# OSError in willson davidson programme

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, astronomy

I am runnning the python script pywd2015.py. Everything goes fine till i create a light curve. I get the following error.

```
qt.xkb.compose: failed to create compose table Traceback (most recent call last):   File      "/home/anil/astronomylab/Wilsion devinay /src/interfaces/syntheticcurve_interface.py", line 288, in plot_selected_light_curve     results = lc_io.fill_for_synthetic_light_curve().save().run().read_synthetic_light_curve()   File "/home/anil/astronomylab/Wilsion devinay /src/helpers/wd_utils/wd_io.py", line 44, in run     self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=self._cwd)   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1845, in _execute_child     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error:      '/home/anil/astronomylab/Wilsion devinay /wd-precompiled/lc_source.obj
```

I have tried to find the solution on internet, but i am unable to get any solution. Plese help to resolve the problem! What is causing it?